# PDO Exception in connection to SQL Server from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, driver

I'm using PHP 7.2.4. I've pasted the dlls php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll, php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll, php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll and php_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll to the php/ext folder and edited the php.ini to extend these dlls. Despite all of this I'm still getting the error: "could not find driver". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you reboot the web server?

Comment: Also, check the output from phpinfo() from a file called by the web server. There are frequently more than one php.ini file, independently for the web server or CLI PHP and it's a common mistake to change the wrong one.